# calculate speed and time

Tags: algebra-precalculus, word-problem

Due to a fuel shortage, the speed limit on a major highway was lowered 5 miles per hour.  Assume that a certain motorist always drives at the legal speed limit.  If he were able to drive 99 miles in 2 1/5 hours at the original speed limit, how long will it take him to drive 100 miles at the new speed limit?

Pls help.  Thanks in advance.

NOTE:  the correct answer is 2 hours and 30 minutes.

Comment: Please read the tag description before using a tag for the first time. This has nothing to do with the tag [tag:elementary-number-theory].

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes it's just easier to use multiple variables to describe the given relationships. For example:
$$V_{\text{old}} = \frac{D_\text{old}}{T_\text{old}}=\frac{99}{2\frac{1}{5}}$$
$$V_\text{new}=V_\text{old}-5$$
$$V_{new}=\frac{D_\text{new}}{T_\text{new}}=\frac{100}{T_\text{new}}\implies T_\text{new}=\frac{100}{V_\text{new}}$$
Now that you have everything in front of you, just substitute away until there is just $T_\text{new}$ remaining.

Answer (score 0):

Outline:

Step 1: Use 99 miles in 2.2 hours to find the old speed limit.

Step 2: Find the new speed limit.

Step 3: Find how long it takes to go 100 miles with new speed limit.

Answer (score 0):

His original speed was $\frac{99 miles}{2.2 hours}=45$ mph, so the new speed limit must be $45-5=40$ mph. Thus $\frac{100 miles}{x hours}=40$ mph. Solving for x, $100/40=2.5$ hours, or 2 hours and 30 minutes.